# Export user profile fields in pdf

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I`m using Drupal 7 and i have added some extra fields in People > Account Settings.

What I`m trying to accomplish is to give logged in user link ( in sidebar block ) to export those fields into .pdf

I created a view with all user fields and i found module called [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

But unfortunately it does not support PDF. Is there any other way/module to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself here.

There is a module [Views PDF](https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) that does the job. Not sure how i missed it earlier...